# c++ cross-platform method for file-io is needed

Tags: c++, file, file-io, cross-platform

Is there any standard cross-platform analogue for file-io in c/c++ to

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

?

Comment: `fopen` is cross-platform, but I assume that you already know that. What functionality are you looking for?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `open`..?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, fopen() limits open file descriptors count to a less number, than open(), as far as i'm aware.

Comment: @Sean I gladly would, but it is not a part of c/c++, so it might not be available on different platforms

Comment: I think the odds on you encountering a platform where it isn't available are pretty slim, and if you do encouter such a platform then you're going to have bigger issues!!

Answer (score 8):

`int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)` is not C++. It is pure C.

You should use `std::fstream`  ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/ )

```
#include <fstream>     

int main () {

  std::fstream fs;
  fs.open ("test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

  fs << " more lorem ipsum";

  fs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need something that can be used in c++ and something that will work with file descriptors, not streams, can you advise anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

File descriptors aren't cross platform, they belong to POSIX standard, so they will work on Linux/Unix-like systems only.